# Display only future database records with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, syntax-error

I am trying to display only records two weeks in advance from the current date onwards. `starttime` is stored as a `datetime` data type in the database.

I have this,

```
       SELECT id, date_format(starttime, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i') AS formatted_start, date_format(starttime, '%Y-%m-%d') AS formatted_date, 
    date_format(endtime, ' %H:%i') AS formatted_end 
    FROM timedates WHERE user_id = 1 AND `status`='' AND  YEARWEEK(formatted_date, 0) IN (YEARWEEK(NOW(), 0), 
YEARWEEK(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK), 0))
```

But I am getting a syntax error `YEARWEEK(formatted_date, 0) IN (YEARWEEK(NOW(), 0) AND YEARWEEK(DATE_ADD(NOW()`

Could anyone tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: why do even use this `YEARWEEK` function? I see no reason for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said, I see no reason to use `YEARWEEK` function. You need start date set to today which is `CURDATE()` and plus 2 weeks period which is `DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)` and then we just check if `starttime` between those 2 dates.

```
SELECT id, date_format(starttime, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i') AS formatted_start,
    date_format(starttime, '%Y-%m-%d') AS formatted_date, 
    date_format(endtime, ' %H:%i') AS formatted_end 
FROM timedates 
WHERE user_id = 1 
  AND `status`='' 
  AND  DATE(starttime) BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
```

Comment: This has worked! Thanks, could you give a bit explanation what I did wrong

Comment: This returns the records in the next 14 days.

Answer (score 1):

It seems MySQL does not support calculated column in the where clause:

try

```
SELECT id, date_format(starttime, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i') AS formatted_start, 
date_format(starttime, '%Y-%m-%d') AS formatted_date, 
date_format(endtime, ' %H:%i') AS formatted_end 
FROM timedates 
WHERE user_id = 1 AND `status`='' AND  
YEARWEEK(starttime, 0) IN (
 YEARWEEK(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK), 0), 
 YEARWEEK(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK), 0))
```

use starttime instead of formatted_date

Comment: This doesn't work. It still displays past dates where it should only display from today's date onwards...

Comment: I didn't check your logic, just help you fix the syntax error. Give me or other guys more time to fix your logical issues. Some sample data should be helpful.

Comment: Try add one week for the first value too.

Comment: Sorry that didn't work. There should be 1 result but instead it's returning nothing. Could it be because the datatype is datetime?

Comment: can you post some real data (dates)? not the number of weeks?

Comment: You need add 2 week for the first and 3 week for the second.

Answer (score 0):

How do you define "two weeks in advance"? Our normal inclination, is to think "within two weeks", which would be to simply before 14 days from now.

```
 WHERE starttime >= NOW()
   AND starttime  < NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY
```

But the original query is using `YEARWEEK` function, and the behavior with that is a bit different.

If today is Thursday, May 21, 1015. What is the range of dates that `starttime` should fall into?

For datetimes right now or in the future, we can just do:

```
 WHERE starttime >= NOW()
```

(We can do just a `>` rather than `>=` if we want to exclude `startime` values that are an exact match for `NOW()`.

The question is, the bit about "two weeks in advance". Adding 14 days, or 2 weeks, would get us up to Thursday, June 4, 2015. It looks like you might also want to include Friday and Saturday, June 5th and 6th. (Up until Sunday, June th.)

We can use an expression to return "Sunday on or following 14 days from today"

If it's a Sunday, we just use that date. (For convenience, we think of that as adding 0 days). If it's Saturday, we need to add 1 day. If it's a Friday, add 2 days, ... Monday, add 6 days.

Conveniently, the expression **`6 - WEEKDAY(NOW())`** gives us the number of days we need to add to today's date to get to the next Sunday.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday

We probably want to lop the time off at midnight, we can use the `DATE()` function to do that.

```
 -- startime values on or after now and before midnight 
 -- of the first sunday on or after the date two weeks from now
 WHERE starttime >= NOW()
   AND starttime <  DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 14+6-WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY
```

It's much easier to read and understand what the query is doing when we reference bare columns from the table on one side, and do the gyration and manipulation on the other side. It's also easier to test. And, maybe more importantly, it allows MySQL to make effective use of an "range scan" operation on a suitable index, rather than having to evaluate a function on every row in the table.

If today is '2015-05-21', and what you meant by "two weeks in advance" was up until the second Sunday from now (Sunday, May 31, 2015... 1 week and 3 days from now) just replace the `14` with `7`.

Again, it really depends on how you define "two weeks in advance", how you determine what that ending date boundary is. Once you can define that, you can write an expression that returns the value, and just compare to value stored in the `starttime` column.